# Tabindex relative to container

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an editor template, which outputs several controls for the object and would like to control the tab index for the various input elements relative to the container for my object.  I may have multiple objects on the page.  The typical display order of the objects does not match with the best entry order, so I want the 5th input element to be the 3rd item tabbed to, and then the 3rd and 4th element to follow.

Is this possible without adjusting the order of the elements in the document? I have tried adding a tabindex to the htmlattributes, and that works if there is only one object on the page (and I want the tab to go to my object out of sequence to the rest of the page).

I'd like to have something like:

```
<div id="sec1">
    <input id="address1" value="1" /> <input id="address2" value="2" /> <br />
    <input id="city" value="3" /> <input id="state" value="4" /> <input id="zip" value="5" /> <br/>
    <input id="country" type="text" value="6" />
</div>
```

I realize I could do this with divs and having the 5th element be immediately after the 2nd, and floating right and then left, but if possible would prefer a solution that doesn't require making the tab sequence match the code sequence.

Comment: What do you mean by 'that works if there is only one object on the page'? The `tabindex` attribute is for this exact issue that you're having.

Comment: @KevinLee: the object knows how to create the div, but has no idea how many other objects of the same type might be on the page.  If I just assign 1, 2, 3 then there will potentially be multiple elements on the page with the same tabindex.  If I use the object id as  base, then they potentially overlap (again causing multiple elments to the same tabindex) and will definitely be thrown out of the normal tab sequence.

Comment: which I don't want it to do.  What I am hoping there is, is some way of saying "within this container, tab to this element first, this one second..."

Comment: You could try incrementing the tabindex for each input group by a large amount, like 100. So the first group has tabindex from 101-105, the second from 201-205, and so on.


Otherwise, if you can't do that, then there's no easy way to solve your issue. You could try using jQuery and data-order attributes to tab to the correct input within each group?